# UICollectionView load Sections Vertically

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collection View and i am using Custom `CollectionViewLayout` for scrolling in both direction. I want to merge the first row items like in the below image,

[image]

Please help me to do this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you have relevant code examples?

Answer (score 0):

Follow to this tutorial: [UICollectionView Custom Layout Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/107439/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest)